# Markov chains properties

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I would like to have some help concerning Markov chains cause it's really getting me confused! Considering the Markov process (Xn), is the following statement always true? For any n1,n2,n3 such that n1<n2<n3 : Xn1→Xn2→Xn3 is a Markov chain.
It seems to be straightforward however still confusing.
Please help! I only want to know if this statement is always true. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: If $X_n$ is a Markov process, then whether or not it is also called a "Markov chain" may depend on whether the state space is discrete, the time parameter is discrete, or neither (i.e. terms used interchangeably), depending on who you ask. See [What is the difference between Markov chains and Markov processes?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/241506/what-is-the-difference-between-markov-chains-and-markov-processes)